# What are the X-subgroups of this right R-module?

Tags: matrices, group-theory, modules, order-theory, noetherian

I'm working through Isaacs' Algebra- A Graduate Course, and I have hit a wall at the chapter on Modules. In particular I am having trouble with Problem 12.24.

Say $B, C \subseteq A$ are unitary subrings of $A$. Let $A_B$ and $_CA$ denote $A$ viewed as a right $B$-module and $A$ viewed as a left $C$-module, respectively. Also, let
$$R =\left\{  \begin{bmatrix}
    b & 0 \\ a & c
\end{bmatrix} \middle\vert a \in A, b \in B, c \in C
\right\} \subseteq M_2(A)$$

and let
$$I = \left\{ 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 \\ a & 0
\end{bmatrix} \middle\vert a \in A
\right\} \subseteq R.$$

The first two parts of the question have us proving that $R$ is a ring and $I$ is an ideal of $R$, then it asks us to show that $R/I \cong B \oplus C$. So those facts are available to us.

We are then asked to show that $I$ is noetherian or artinian as a right $R$-module if and only if $A_B$ is noetherian or artinian, respectively.

In order for $I$ to be noetherian or artinian, it must be an abelian $X$-group and we assign a poset $P$ consisting all $X$-subgroups of $I$ ordered by inclusion. Going by the definition of $X$-subgroup, $H \subseteq G$ is an $X$-subgroup if for every $x \in X$ and $h \in H$, we have $h^{x} \in H$.

It seems to me that every matrix $x \in I$ is singular. So how is it possible for $h^x = x^{-1}hx \in H \subseteq X$? What exactly do the $X$-subgroups "*look like*" ?

Comment: I am afraid that I cannot make much sense of what you have written. What are $X$, $H$, and $G$ supposed to be? To say that $I$ is Noetherian as a right $R$-module means that it satsifies the ascending chain condition on its right $R$-submodules. There are no groups involved apart from their additive structures. In fact the exercise looks straightforward because multiplying an element of $I$ on the right by an element of $R$ simply results in the entry $a$ being replaced by $ab$.

Comment: Sorry, after looking back at what I wrote, It definitely seems like nonsense now.

At the moment I suppose I'm a little foggy about how exactly $I$ satisfying the ascending chain condition on its right $R$-submodules relates to $A_B$ being noetherian or artinian. 

Is it because multiplying an element of $I$ on the right by an element of $R$ will always result in an element in $I$? So this ascending chain would only satisfy the maximal/minimal condition if $ab \in B$? something like that?

Comment: It is really because the submodules of $I$ as a right $R$-module correspond exactly to the right ideals of $A_B$. If I have understood it correctly, then it is one of those problems where the solution becomes obvious once you have sorted out and understood what everything means.